# Include email verification within signUpInBackgroundWithBlock function

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have implemented the following function (attached to the "register button") within my registration view controller as seen below. The function relies upon Parse and is seamless in general.

However I am encountering the following issues at present:

1. If a user inserts an invalid email address by mistake; the error string listed under "else" is activated (which is good) but the username and password entered above are registered regardless.
2. Users are able to leave the password field blank.

Any help whatsoever, especially pertaining to issue 1, would be immensely appreciated.

[image: registerViewController]

```
// Register user.
- (IBAction)registerUser:(id)sender
{
PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
user.username = self.mobileTextField.text;
user.password = self.passwordTextField.text;
user.email = self.emailTextField.text;

// Show loading HUD.
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userRegistered" sender:self];
     }
     else
     {
         NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
         UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"                                                 message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [errorAlertView show];

         // Dismiss loading HUD.
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
         });
     }
 }];

// End editing.
[self.view endEditing: YES];

});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems here.

a, you absolutely **do not need to and should not** take a new thread.  **Parse does that for you.**  You must change it.

b, you may be looking for the magic formula in parse "if ( (!succeeded) || error)..."

c, you should really **locally check** that the email is valid before sending it. (ie, you can't enter "xyz@hotmail" or something not sensible as an email.)

ie, you need to write a routine like "checkThisEmailIsValid".  if you need help with his yell out.  note that it's not that easy conceptually. you understand that parse will try to verify the email right?  ie it will send one of those emails "new user, click here to verify your email!"  You're familiar with that?

d, a great secret is the 202 error code

Here's some example code from a production app, hope it helps!

```
-(void)_actuallyJoin
   {
   ... do things like check the email is valid

   ... in this app the username is the lowercase email

   PFUser *nuser = [PFUser user];
   nuser.username = [self.email.text lowercaseString];

   ... in this app, the email is the email, password is the password

   nuser.email = self.email.text;
   nuser.password = self.password.text;

   [APP huddie];
   APP.hud.labelText = @"Registering ...";
   APP.hud.detailsLabelText = @"1 of 3 ...";
   ... that is just MBProgressHUD.

   [nuser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
      {
      if ( (!succeeded) || error)
         {
         [APP.hud hide:YES]; .. that's MBProgressHUD

         .. usually, blank the form while app is connecting
         self.email.text = @"";
         self.password.text = @"";
         self.confirmPassword.text = @"";

         if ( error.code == 202 )
            {
            [PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"newAccount"
               dimensions:@{ @"result":@"emailAlreadyUsed" }];

            [self woe:@"That email address is already in use...."];
            [PFUser logOut]; .. don't forget that
            return;
            }

         [PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"newAccount"
            dimensions:@{ @"result":@"connectionWoe" }];
         [self woe:@"Couldn't connect. Please try later"];
         return;
         }

      NSLog(@"step one rego success");
      [self _actuallyJoinStepTwo];
      ... now continue to save other information
      ... for example user's address, age, avatar photo etc.
      }];
   }
```